# On Windows, when a Python script gets its argv, has parsing been done by python.exe's MS C Runtime?

Tags: python, windows, command-line

On Windows, when a Python script gets its `argv`,  has parsing been done by the MS C Runtime?

Does the windows implementation of Python use the MS C Runtime to get its `argv`, then pass arguments to a script's `argv`, by inspecting its own `argv`, removing the first element that has the path to `python.exe`, and passing rest of `argv` on?

If not, then I'm wondering where is the documentation for the built in python library that feeds the command line to `argv`, in Windows programs?

I will include some example programs that give some background to what I am talking about

```
    C:\blah>type w.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf(GetCommandLine());
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    C:\blah>w.exe "asdf" fff
    w.exe  "asdf" fff
    C:\blah>

    C:\blah>type w2.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
            int i = 0;
            while (argv[i]) {
                    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
                    i++;
            }
            return 0;
    }
    
    C:\blah>w2 "asdf" fff
    argv[0] = w2
    argv[1] = asdf
    argv[2] = fff
    
    C:\blah>
```

In C, the thing that converts the Command Line  (maybe what is shown by `GetCommandLine()`), to `argv`, is called the MS C Runtime Library, and it is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-170)

The C program that uses `argv` is using the MS C Runtime library. [Parsing C command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-170) that's implicitly imported/included and implicitly called.

And by the way here is the Python equivalent of those.

```
C:\blah>type wpyth.py

    import  win32api
    # pip install pywin32  ,   pip install pypiwin32
    
    print(win32api.GetCommandLine())

C:\blah>

C:\blah>wpyth.py asdf werwe<ENTER>
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe "C:\blah\wpyth.py"  asdf werwe

C:\blah>
```

or, more normally.. it can use `argv`:

```
    C:\blah>type w2pyth.py
    
    import sys
    
    for n, a in enumerate(sys.argv): print(f"argv[{n}] = {a}")
    
    C:\blah>

    C:\blah>w2pyth.py asdf werwe
    argv[0] = C:\blah\w2pyth.py
    argv[1] = asdf
    argv[2] = werwe
    
    C:\blah>

    C:\blah>python w2pyth.py asdf werwe
    argv[0] = w2pyth.py
    argv[1] = asdf
    argv[2] = werwe
    
    C:\blah>
```

I would think Yes, because python scripts are run by a python executable which is probably written in C, and that seems like the easiest way it would go about things.

Though am not sure, so am asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments), CPython (the original Python runtime) directly inherits its command line arguments from its C base.  Explained more in-depth at https://nullprogram.com/blog/2022/02/18, C splits the arguments, which are passed to the program as a single string, by whitespace and some quotation/backslash escape handling. However, it's also mentioned that implementations vary, even between Microsoft's own runtimes, and the language does not define an exact algorithm. After the arguments are split, they're passed to the program as an array of strings, which are then usable for whatever you like, in Python.

If working with both C and Python, you may notice the lack of `argc` in Python, and only having `argv`, due to it's high-level features like lengths from arrays and enumerables. C requires `argc`, just in case you need to use them, since it does not have the same level of abstraction as Python.